# Evaluate the indefinite integral $\int \frac{\cos \theta}{ \sqrt{2 - 9 \sin^2 \!\theta}} \mathrm{d}\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I want to evaluate $$\int \dfrac{\cos \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta}{ \sqrt{2 - 9 \sin^2 \theta}}$$

but I can't seem to get the answer, my working is as below:
[image]

Comment: Hint: Let $ x = \frac{\sqrt 2}3 \sin\theta $

Comment: I have done till that, but it's after that step that I am facing problems with..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint
$$\int\dfrac{\cos{\theta}}{\sqrt{2-9\sin^2{\theta}}}d\theta=\int\dfrac{d\sin{\theta}}{\sqrt{2-9\sin^2{\theta}}}$$
and
$$\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2-9t^2}}dt=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}t\right)^2}}dt=\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}t\right)^2}}d\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}t\right)$$

Comment: Still clueless :(

Comment: can you find $\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2-9t^2}}dt?$

Comment: ok i get your step now, but I don't know how to proceed from the step in your comment, no I don't. Sorry, this is new to me

Comment: Now I have edit more hint

Answer (score 1):

Using the substitution $u = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \sin \theta \implies \dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \, \cos \theta$. Our integral can be written as $$\int \dfrac{\cos \theta}{ \sqrt{2 - 9 \sin^2 \theta}} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}u} \mathrm{d}u = \int \dfrac{\cos \theta}{ \sqrt{2 - 9 \sin^2 \theta}} \, \cdot \frac{3 \sec \theta}{\sqrt{2}} \mathrm{d}u$$

So $$\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 - 9 \sin^2 \theta}} \, \mathrm{d}u = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 - (81u^2/2)}} \, \mathrm{d}u$$

And hence we get

$$\int \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2 - (81u^2/2)}} \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{3} \arcsin \left(\frac{9u}{2}\right) + \mathrm{C}$$.

Back substituting yields

$$\frac{1}{3} \arcsin \left(\frac{3 \sin \theta}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + \mathrm{C}$$

Comment: in line 2, where is $\sqrt(2-(81u^2/2)$ coming from?

Comment: If $u = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \sin \theta$ then re-arranging we have $\sin \theta =\frac{3u}{\sqrt{2}}$. Squaring and multiply by $9$ gives us $9 \sin^2 \theta = 9 \cdot \frac{9u^2}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And finally, is line 3 an identity? what is the formula of the identity?

Comment: It's a standard formula, you can look it up. It's of the form $$\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ where $a$ is some real number. If this answered your question, mark it as accepted by pressing the green tick and upvoting. :)

Comment: Why can we not take 2 as $(\sqrt 2)^2$ and just put in the general formula?

Comment: I see no reason why you can't!

Comment: Final question, sorry, if I could do that, where would the 1/3 come from?

Comment: and in $$\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 - 9 \sin^2 \theta}} \, \mathrm{d}u = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \int \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2 - (81u^2/2)}} \, \mathrm{d}u$$, where does the 3 above fraction in second statement come from?

Comment: It was a mistake, thanks for spotting it! :)